# What is $\sigma(q^k)$ in terms of $k$ if $q \equiv 5 \pmod 8$?

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, alternative-proof, divisor-sum

Denote the sum of divisors of $x \in \mathbb{N}$ by $\sigma(x)$.

Here is my question:

> What is $\sigma(q^k)$ in terms of $k$ if $q \equiv 5 \pmod 8$?

I know that if $q \equiv 1 \pmod 8$, then
$$\sigma(q^k) = \sum_{i=0}^{k}{q^i} \equiv 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{k}{q^i} \equiv 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{k}{1^i} \equiv k + 1 \pmod 8,$$
but I am having trouble trying to wrap my head around the corresponding derivation for the case when $q \equiv 5 \pmod 8$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

I first computed the residues of powers of $5$ modulo $8$:
$$5^0 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$$
$$5^1 \equiv 5 \pmod 8$$
$$5^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$$
$$5^3 \equiv 5 \pmod 8$$
etc.

Therefore, I get:
$$\sigma(q^k) \equiv
\begin{cases}
1 \pmod 8, \text{ if } k \equiv 0 \pmod 8 \\
1 + 5 \equiv 6 \pmod 8, \text{ if } k \equiv 1 \pmod 8 \\
6 + 1 \equiv 7 \pmod 8, \text{ if } k \equiv 2 \pmod 8 \\
7 + 5 \equiv 4 \pmod 8, \text{ if } k \equiv 3 \pmod 8 \\
4 + 1 \equiv 5 \pmod 8, \text{ if } k \equiv 4 \pmod 8 \\
5 + 5 \equiv 2 \pmod 8, \text{ if } k \equiv 5 \pmod 8 \\
2 + 1 \equiv 3 \pmod 8, \text{ if } k \equiv 6 \pmod 8 \\
3 + 5 \equiv 0 \pmod 8, \text{ if } k \equiv 7 \pmod 8 \\
\end{cases}
$$

> Is my derivation correct?